# Unregistered token Android Firebase messaging (Xamarin)

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to receive notifications via Firebase Messaging, I already parsed my google-services.json and I'm retrieving the token on the OnCreate() method. I also have OnTokenRefresh() implemented.

When I fill the notification and click send via Firebase console, I do not receive the notification on my device, I already tried with both Debug and Release options but nothing happened.

Sooner than later, the console will show a failed status on my notification because of an unregistered token.

Any ideas on how can I fix it?

PD: I'm using this for it to work in Debug mode:

```
    private void ConfigureFireBase()
    {

     #if DEBUG

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var instanceId = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance;
            instanceId.DeleteInstanceId();
            Android.Util.Log.Debug("TAG", "{0} {1}", instanceId?.Token?.ToString(), instanceId.GetToken(GetString(Resource.String.gcm_defaultSenderId), Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.InstanceIdScope));

        });

        // For debug mode only - will accept the HTTPS certificate of Test/Dev server, as the HTTPS certificate is invalid /not trusted
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, certificate, chain, errors) => true;


     #endif
    }
```

Comment: Since you never receive the notification, it's possible that something is wrong with your receiver, and if package name does not exactly match the package name that was entered into the Firebase Console, you won't receive the token, maybe you should refer to [Remote Notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/).

Comment: Most likely it's related to the receiver, but I did everything that documentation said (the one you posted is the same I used, and I made sure to follow it step by step). The package name, app id and project id match on visual studio and firebase console.

Comment: Update: I just fixed it. The issue is I was debugging with android 6. As soon as I tried it with android 5, it worked just fine. I found notifications will not work in android 6 while being in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I was trying to get the notifications in android 6 while on debug mode. I had to swtich to android 5 and leave the application running on the background. It worked just fine.

note: If you leave the app running in foreground, the push notification will not be displayed.